# Notification not being scheduled Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to let a user be able to set a custom date and time for a notification. I have created a `NofiticationPublisher` class that extends `BroadcastReciver` to handle setting it. Whenever I try to call it, it doesn't work. What is wrong with my code?

NotificationPublisher:

```
    public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        String name = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
        String description = intent.getStringExtra("Description");
        int id = intent.getIntExtra("Id", 0); // 0 is default
        NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        b.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_check)
                .setContentTitle(name)
                .setContentText(description)
                .setTicker("Ticker test");
        notificationManager.notify(id , b.build());
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="xxx.xxx.xxx">
<uses-permission android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".example1" />
    <activity android:name=".example2" />
    <receiver android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.NotificationPublisher" android:enabled="true" />
</application>
```

Part of the activity that creates the notification:

```
        if(notifications == true) {
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class); 
        intentAlarm.putExtra("Name", name);
        intentAlarm.putExtra("Description", description);
        intentAlarm.putExtra("Id", id);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, (System.currentTimeMillis() + 5 * 1000), pendingIntent); // The time is an example
}
```

Comment: `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` is based on the time since boot. `System.currentTimeMillis()` is "wall clock" time. Your alarm is scheduled _waaay_ in the future.

Comment: If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Cool. It's a common slip, however, so I'll just mark this as a duplicate, since I've answered an issue like this before. Thanks, though. Glad you got it working. Cheers!